# EF Core 3 Scaffolding (Database first) does not generate Primary Key Fluent API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have scoffeled all my models for the project from an existing database, using EntityFramework's `Scaffold-DbContext` command.

EntityFramework did a perfect job in creating all of the models mapped to a table and generating the `Fluent API` fonfiguration code.

From what I have noticed, the `Fluent API` code is missing the configuration of the `Primary Key` field, although it has added the propery to the generated model.

Here is an example of one of my generated classes and its corresponding `Fluent API` code:

```
public partial class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; } //Primary Key
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyAccountTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyAccountGroupId { get; set; }
    public int? RegionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string IncludeEscalationEmail { get; set; }
    public decimal? Gpslat { get; set; }
    public decimal? Gpslong { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Vatnumber { get; set; }
    public bool AutoReceive { get; set; }
    public bool AutoIssue { get; set; }
    public bool? IsBillableToAccount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BillingStart { get; set; }
    public bool? IsEquipmentDepot { get; set; }
    public bool? IsShiftAttendanceEnabled { get; set; }
    public int? ShiftMinHoursForLunchDeduction { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? NightShiftStart { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? NightShiftEnd { get; set; }
    public int? ShiftStartDayOfMonth { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? OperatingHoursStart { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? OperatingHoursEnd { get; set; }
    public int? LoadBays { get; set; }
    public int? LoadInterval { get; set; }
    public int? ArrivalInterval { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? OverrideStockTakeCloseBalanceTime { get; set; }
    public bool? TempIgnoreVendorIssueViaSap { get; set; }
    public bool Archived { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedByPersonId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedByPersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyAccountGroup CompanyAccountGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyAccountType CompanyAccountType { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountBalance> AccountBalance { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountContact> AccountContact { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountEquipment> AccountEquipment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountHrlookup> AccountHrlookup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountPickVolumeDefault> AccountPickVolumeDefaultAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountPickVolumeDefault> AccountPickVolumeDefaultPartnerAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountPickVolumeDetail> AccountPickVolumeDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountPickVolumePartner> AccountPickVolumePartner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppUserAccount> AppUserAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BiometricTerminal> BiometricTerminal { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyVendorAccount> CompanyVendorAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EquipmentCheck> EquipmentCheckAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EquipmentCheck> EquipmentCheckAccountMaintenance { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GantryTransfer> GantryTransferCreditAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GantryTransfer> GantryTransferDebitAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> OrderDepotAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> OrderPrimaryAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rfequipment> Rfequipment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RfmoveTransaction> RfmoveTransactionPartnerAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RfmoveTransaction> RfmoveTransactionPrimaryAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShiftCalendar> ShiftCalendar { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShiftSchedule> ShiftSchedule { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShiftTeam> ShiftTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransferDeviance> TransferDevianceIssueAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransferDeviance> TransferDevianceIssuePartnerAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransferDeviance> TransferDevianceReceiptAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransferDeviance> TransferDevianceReceiptPartnerAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransferJournal> TransferJournalCreditAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransferJournal> TransferJournalDebitAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transfer> TransferPartnerAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transfer> TransferPrimaryAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VehicleCheckIn> VehicleCheckIn { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<XAppUserAccountAccess> XAppUserAccountAccess { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Fluent API:

```
builder.HasIndex(e => new { e.AccountId, e.CompanyAccountTypeId, e.Name, e.Code, e.CompanyId })
                .HasName("IX_AccountCompanyType");

        builder.HasIndex(e => new { e.Archived, e.AccountId, e.UpdatedDate, e.CompanyId, e.CompanyAccountTypeId, e.CompanyAccountGroupId, e.RegionId })
            .HasName("IX_AppUserAccountAccess");

        builder.HasIndex(e => new { e.AccountId, e.CompanyId, e.CompanyAccountGroupId, e.RegionId, e.Name, e.Gpslong, e.BillingStart, e.Code, e.Address, e.Email, e.IncludeEscalationEmail, e.Gpslat, e.ArrivalInterval, e.Telephone, e.Vatnumber, e.AutoReceive, e.AutoIssue, e.IsBillableToAccount, e.UpdatedDate, e.IsEquipmentDepot, e.OperatingHoursStart, e.OperatingHoursEnd, e.LoadBays, e.LoadInterval, e.UpdatedByPersonId, e.OverrideStockTakeCloseBalanceTime, e.TempIgnoreVendorIssueViaSap, e.Archived, e.CreatedDate, e.CreatedByPersonId, e.CompanyAccountTypeId })
            .HasName("IX_vAccount");

        builder.Property(e => e.Address)
            .HasMaxLength(500)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        builder.Property(e => e.BillingStart).HasColumnType("date");

        builder.Property(e => e.Code)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedByPersonId).HasColumnName("CreatedBy_PersonId");

        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

        builder.Property(e => e.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(200)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        builder.Property(e => e.Gpslat)
            .HasColumnName("GPSLat")
            .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 6)");

        builder.Property(e => e.Gpslong)
            .HasColumnName("GPSLong")
            .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 6)");

        builder.Property(e => e.IncludeEscalationEmail)
            .HasMaxLength(500)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        builder.Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        builder.Property(e => e.Telephone)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        builder.Property(e => e.TempIgnoreVendorIssueViaSap).HasColumnName("temp_IgnoreVendorIssueViaSAP");

        builder.Property(e => e.UpdatedByPersonId).HasColumnName("UpdatedBy_PersonId");

        builder.Property(e => e.UpdatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

        builder.Property(e => e.Vatnumber)
            .HasColumnName("VATNumber")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        builder.HasOne(d => d.CompanyAccountGroup)
            .WithMany(p => p.Account)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyAccountGroupId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Account_CompanyAccountGroup");

        builder.HasOne(d => d.CompanyAccountType)
            .WithMany(p => p.Account)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyAccountTypeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Account_CompanyAccountType");

        builder.HasOne(d => d.Company)
            .WithMany(p => p.Account)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Account_Company");

        builder.HasOne(d => d.Region)
            .WithMany(p => p.Account)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.RegionId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Account_Region");
```

As you can see, my model has the Primary Key field named `AccountId`.  Why does the mapping for this not get added in the Fluent API code?

Comment: have you tried [Key] with the AccountId?

Answer (score 0):

It's not being added, because it's a convention that this property is the primary key.

From [Conventions in Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions):

> If a property is named `ID` or `<entity name>ID` (not case-sensitive), it will be configured as the primary key. Entity Framework Core will prefer `ID` over `<entity name>ID` in the event that a class contains both.